# Adding custom PublishingRollUpImage to pagelayout

Tags: publishing-page, spfield

Is it possible to create your own PublishingRollUpImage. Do I need to map Crawl properties with new Managed Properties to make the new one act like a PublishingRollUpImage when it comes to search results.

Comment: I presume you need more than one? That you are already using the PublishingRollUpImage in the content type?

Comment: I am in an udd situation, the clients wants to have a new PublishingRollUpImage (new Site column) and does not want to use the oob one.